# Creating a colored line across the size of the window?

Tags: html, xampp

How would I do this?
The subject isn't very explained, so for an example: the black line at the top of the footer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean <hr />?

You can use CSS to set the colour and size, e.g.

```
hr {
    height:25px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```